# x-frame-options sameorigin while loading extrenal page in my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, live-tile

we need to Load external web site and show it as a live website tile in our application where x-frame-options set to same origin for the external website.

We followed below approaches but nothing is working.

Please help us to know any framework/approach to achieve this.

Iframe : < iFrame src="www.xyz.com">

Ajax Approach : Ajax HttpGet Call to the external web siteand get the html and render on our website.But replacing the image, css and html links from html is not working properly.

Web Request Approach : Server side HttpGet Call to the external web siteand get the html and render on our website.But replacing the image, css and html links from html is not working properly.

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like what you are trying to do is not possible without iframes. Try including some code so we might get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that you can do this. The whole idea behind x-frame-options with the same-orign setting is to prevent what you are trying to do. It is to avoid clickjacking attacks.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options